# How to updating specific data from DB at specific periode

Tags: javascript, php

What is the way to keep update the info about if user has got new notifications?

When page is opened it includes content of pageTop.php. There it checks database, if there are some unchecked notification. And loads note_NO or note_YES in base of query.

How is the approach to have new info at certain time period ?

Next page works on page load or refresh.  But I don't want to reload header.php each time.

header.php:

```
<?php include_once("pageTop.php");?>
<div id="pageMidle"></div>
<div id="pageFoot"></div>
```

pageTop:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM note WHERE user='$l_user' AND did_read ='0' ";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

$nrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows == 0) {
    $envelope = '<a href="notifications.php" title="No notifications"><img src="images/note_NO.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Notes"></a>';
} else {
    $envelope = '<a href="notifications.php" title="You have new notifications"><img src="/images/note_YES.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="Notes"></a>';
}
```

html:

```
  <div id="envolopeDIV">
          <?php echo $envelope; ?> 
      </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a session to keep track of time between requests in the backend. If your specified time period has passed, include the snippet for querying the database.

```php
session_start();
const TIME_PERIOD = 123456;
$currentTimestamp = time();
$previousTimestamp = $_SESSION['previous_timestamp'] ?? 0;
if ($previousTimestamp + TIME_PERIOD > $currentTimestamp) {
    // check notifications
}
$_SESSION['previous_timestamp'] = $currentTimestamp;
//...
```